# Pre-commit hook based on an executable (not git repo)

Tags: pre-commit

I'd like to run executable coming from pip that isn't available as a git repository. It seems that documentation assumes anything you'd like to run comes from git repositories: https://pre-commit.com/#plugins. How can I run arbitrary shell commands as pre-commit hooks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pre-commit allows to use `local` sentinel for a repo section. The example config below runs black as installed on the system:

```yaml
repos:
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    - id: black
      name: black
      language: system
      entry: black
      types: [python]
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to expand on the accepted answer with an example on how to run any script in your repository.

Say you have a new hook `build/hooks/my-hook.js` that you implemented on top of nodejs. Lets also say this new hook wants to operate on `jsonnet` type files.

Here is how you can trigger it with pre-commit

```
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    - id: my-hook
      name: my-hook
      language: system
      entry: node
      args: [build/hooks/my-plugin.js]
      types: [jsonnet]
```

`entry` - points to the executable we want to run. In our case - node.
`args` - the arguments we send to nodejs. The first one will be which file to execute. The plugin will get the filenames to run on from pre-commit.

So for example `process.argv` will include:

- path/to/node
- path/to/build/hooks/my-plugin.js
- file1.jsonnet
- file2.jsonnet
- ...

```
// build/hooks/my-plugin.js

console.log(process.argv)
```

to see the output, remember to use the verbose flag

```
pre-commit run --verbose
```

## How to make the plugin to fail when needed?

pre-commit will automatically identify if the plugin modified a staged file and will fail the commit.

Alternatively, if your plugin does not change files, simply call exit with code 1 - pre-commit will honor that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can run a bash script or a tool installed via pip (in my case ruff).

```yaml
repos:
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: check-k8s-scripts
        name: Check K8's Scripts
        entry: ./precommits.sh
        language: system
        stages: [pre-push]
      - id: check-code-issues
        name: Check Code Issues
        entry: ruff check .
        language: python
        stages: [pre-push]
        exclude: ^tests/
        files: .*\.py$
```